# Nginx Ingress rewrite-target gives 308, service is working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, http-redirect, microk8s

I have an app set up which can be contacted via the service-IP, but not using the Ingress Rule.

Consider the following Ingress Manifest:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$0
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: letsencrypt-prod
    hosts:
    - my.host.net
  rules:
  - host: my.host.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /myapp(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapp
            port:
              number: 1234
```

The relevant service is up and running. Doing a `curl 10.152.183.91/myapp/path/` with `10.152.183.91` being the service IP gives the desired result.

When I go through `curl my.host.net/myapp/path/` however, I get a `308 Permanent Redirect`. Other apps on the same cluster are running as expected, so the cluster itself as well as nginx-ingress and CoreDNS are doing their job.

Where did I go wrong? Is the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$0` wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you will need to change the:

- from: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$0`
- to: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`

Explanation:

> ### [Rewrite Target](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target)
>
> #### Note
>
> [Captured groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) are saved in numbered placeholders, chronologically, in the form $1, $2 ... $n. These placeholders can be used as parameters in the `rewrite-target` annotation.
>
> Create an Ingress rule with a rewrite annotation:
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   annotations:
>     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
>      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
>   name: rewrite
>   namespace: default
> spec:
>   ingressClassName: nginx
>   rules:
>   - host: rewrite.bar.com
>     http:
>       paths:
>       - path: /something(/|$)(.*)
>         pathType: Prefix
>         backend:
>           service:
>             name: http-svc
>             port: 
>               number: 80
> ```
>
> In this ingress definition, any characters captured by `(.*)` will be assigned to the placeholder `$2`, which is then used as a parameter in the `rewrite-target` annotation.
>
> For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:
>
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/new` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/new`
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Examples: Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)*

---

As for the `curl` part. By running exactly the same as you did:

- `curl my.host.net/myapp/path/`

You will receive a `308 Permanent Redirect`.

`curl` by default is not following the redirection. Try with `curl -L`.

Example with setup similar to yours:

```bash
❯ curl kruklabs.internal/myapp/      
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

❯ curl kruklabs.internal/myapp/ -L -k  
Here is the nginx container!
```

> A side note!
>
> You could also try to contact `Ingress` directly with `HTTPS`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `-L`. This pointed me towards the redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't even need to do any redirection, since my app was listening to the endpoint `/myapp/` anyways. So any request hitting my server at the `/myapp/path` already had the correct URL.

I figured this out when `curl -L` showed a redirect loop (as pointed out by @dawik-kruk)